# How to resolve 521 errors on a cloudflare CNAME record

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, cloudflare, amazon-eks

I've done this a dozen times before but this time, I cannot seem to connect to my web server using HTTPS. I created an `AWS EKS` cluster using `eksctl`. I deployed my deployments and services using `kubectl`. I have service URLs which are resolving on port `80`.

I take the service URL's, put them in `CNAME` records, and Cloudflare resolves via `http` but not `https`. I get `521` errors, when I accept connections on port `443` in my `Kubernetes` services, I get `SSL handshake` errors.

The thing that confuses me is I thought Cloudflare provided an `SSL` layer but using my service URLs on port `80`. It seems though that it's redirecting requests from `cloudflare:443` to `my-eks-cluster:443`.

How do I debug this further to get some insight into what is going on ?

Comment: There are some frequent root causes documented at this page https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-521-web-server-is-down/42461 - anything rings a bell from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your cluster works and accepts traffic, then the most probable reason is that `Encription mode` is enabled in yours Cloudflare config.

And, according to your post, you are going to disable `https` at all on the origin side:

> The thing that confuses me is I thought Cloudflare provided an SSL layer but using my service URLs on port 80. It seems though that it's redirecting requests from cloudflare:443 to my-eks-cluster:443.

So, you may want to check SSL settings to be sure that current `Encription mode` is `Off`

As per Cloudlare documentation:
[Encryption modes · Cloudflare SSL docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes)

> Mode `Off`
> Setting your encryption mode to **Off (not recommended)** redirects any HTTPS request to plaintext HTTP.

Comment: You're amazing! That was it. I changed the setting to "flexible". So the user still sees HTTPS, it encrypts between user and cloudflare but not between cloudflare and my service URL :), which i think is fine.